# Creating a pedigree chart layout with graphviz

Tags: graph, binary-tree, graphviz, graph-layout

[Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) has some powerful [graph layout](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/) algorithms.

But can it lay out a binary tree as depicted below? With the top node in the middle of the page, with each parent fanning out to the side.

Which graphviz tool could I employ to recreate this layout?

[image: pedigree chart]

Comment: You probably will be better of with a tree package in LaTeX.